# Right clicking the top bar of Google Chrome doesn't show the default context menu

Tags: google-chrome, 19.04

Whenever I right-click the top bar of Google Chrome I get a context menu which is not the same in other windows such as nautilus.

For example, in nautilus' context menu there is an option to `stick the window to the visible workspace`.

How can I get that context menu in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome (and Firefox) now also use client side decorations, but as these are not really GTK3 programs (although they get a "dressing" to integrate sufficiently well), they implement their own right-click menu. Thus, you will not be able to access the usual window menu with the mouse. Still, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to reveal the menu and have it stick to the current workspace.

Not perfect, but that is because of the diversity within the Linux ecosystem.

Comment: Even though is not perfect it is still a solution! Thank you.

Comment: @vanadium tab clicking right and middle mouse doesn't work, do you know a reason?